# State in external hook not updating on page - React

Tags: reactjs, list, react-hooks, state, rerender

I have a hook which stored a list of countries.

```
const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] =
    useState(countries);
```

When I filter them in the hook,

```
  setFilteredCountries(filteredCountries.filter(item => item.name !== selectedCountry)
```

they get updated

```
console.log(filteredCountries.length); // shows one less then the previous
```

In my page,  the filtered options never update. How can I trigger this?

```
 const {  filteredCountries } = useCountries();

<select>
     { filteredCountries.map(country =>
       <option>{ country.name }</option>
       )}
</select>
```

I suspect this is the initial value with all 241 countries and there is no rerender.

Comment: Have you tried with `setFilteredCountries(prev => prev.filter(item => item.name !== selectedCountry)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple fiddle that seems to work as expected. Maybe it will give you an idea of what's going wrong in your code. Or you can make a fiddle that demonstrates your issue.

```js
const countries = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function useCountries(except) {
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = React.useState(countries);

  React.useEffect(
    () => setFilteredCountries(filteredCountries.filter(
      (c) => c !== except
    )),
    [except]
  );
  
  React.useEffect(
    () => {console.info('Except:', except);},
    [except]
  );

  return filteredCountries;
}

function App() {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = React.useState();
  const filteredCountries = useCountries(selectedCountry);
  const setException = React.useCallback(
    (e) => {
      console.info('Clicked', e.target, e.target.textContent);
      setSelectedCountry(e.target.textContent);
    },
    []
  );

return (
    <ul>
      {
        filteredCountries.map((c) => <li key={c} onClick={setException}>{c}</li>)
      }
    </ul>
  );
}

const container = document.getElementById('app');
// Create a root.
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
// Initial render
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```